# Like with the results of a subquery (multiple values)

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is the following concept:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3 
FROM table1 
where field3 like '%'+(SELECT distinct field from table2)+'%'
```

But this is not allowed because like does not accept multiple values. How can I rewrite this query so I can wildcard match a field with multiple result values from another table?

Comment: MySQL has `||` or `CONCAT()` for concatenation. Didn't this query produce error?

Comment: @ypercube yes it did, that's why I'm asking an alternate method.

Comment: this is not a answer but a question related to above conversation. I am not able to comment so I am writing here I wrote following query i.e I added and condition but Its showing each entry two times why output is just double? SELECT t1.* FROM `TABLE 4` t1 JOIN (SELECT `PDB` AS fieldx FROM `TABLE 5`) t2 ON t1.`PROTEIN` like 'dimer' and t1.`SP_PDBID` like CONCAT('%',fieldx,'%');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite it into a JOIN

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3 
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN
    (SELECT distinct field AS fieldx from table2) t2 
    ON t1.field3 like CONCAT('%',fieldx,'%')
```

Comment: That is perfect. I count event participants by filter them on email extension with compare it with their company domains :
`SELECT COUNT(email) as count FROM table1 t1 
JOIN (
SELECT company_domains as emailext FROM table2 WHERE company = 'DELL'
)  t2 
ON t1.email LIKE CONCAT('%', emailext) WHERE t1.event='PC Global Conference";`